# Node.Js webserver won't access data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, restful-authentication

I just went through a tutorial and made a simple restful api. Afterwards, I added an admin user to my database. When I run the server, the authentication works, but if I try to access data via the api from the browser I get the eternal "waiting for response from localhost". I'm not sure what else I need to do for the request to be processed now that I've included a user authentication in mongodb.

```html
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://admin:password@localhost/bookstore?authSource=admin");
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello World");
});
```

When going to localhost:3000/ I see hello world, but localhost:3000/api/books won't return anything

```html
app.get("/api/books", function(req, res){
    Genre.getBooks(function(err, books){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(books);
    });
});
```

Here's the getBooks function

```html
module.exports.getBooks = function(callback, limit){
    Book.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

Comment: Is your error handler returning anything?

Comment: No, it didn't. That's why I'm so lost as where to start looking for the problem

Comment: Do you have an error handler?

Comment: The reason i ask is... either the route isn't being reached, an error is being thrown, or json is being returned. "nothing" happening is highly unlikely.

Comment: Your symptoms, *"I get the eternal "waiting for response from localhost""* indicates that you aren't handling errors in such a way that results in a response being sent to the client.

Comment: Typically in express you use the `next` method that gets passed into your request handler to indicate to express that an error has occurred so that the expres error handler (either the default one or one you defined) can handle it. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Correction, I don't have an error handler - edit: I'm going to check that out

Comment: Ok, after including the default error handler, when I go to localhost:3000/api/books I get "Cannot GET /api/books"

Comment: and what status code do you get? 404? 500?

Comment: Sorry, I get a 404

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to getBooks and just respond with plain text?

Comment: That works. I get whatever text I put in the response

Answer (score 1):

You're not in any way handling the callbacks from Node correctly.  You also haven't defined what Genre or Book is in your answer.

That said, a couple notes.  First, if you are in a callback, you never want to throw an error (as in don't use the syntax `throw err`), instead you want to either handle it or pass it back to your calling code.

A common approach I use would be like this:

```
app.get("/api/books", function(req, res, next){ // note adding next here
    Genre.getBooks(function(err, books){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.json(books);
    });
});

// sometime later, a generic error middleware.  You can make yours more useful
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(500).send({ message: 'An error has occurred' });
});
```

<s>Your mongoclient connection and `getBooks` syntax are also probably wrong, but I can't advise you the best way to fix it without knowing if you're using Mongoose or if you're doing something else.</s>

Ok, so since you're using Mongoose, you should remove the MongoClient code you have. Instead, add at app startup:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('your connectionstring here');
```

and your `getBooks` should look like this:

```
module.exports.getBooks = function(callback, limit){
    Book.find({}).limit(limit).exec(callback);
};
```

As a sidenote, node apps typically use the callback as the final argument in a parameter list, so you might want to change the function signature to `(limit, callback)` and adjust the calling code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I didn't have mongoose properly set as the client, so when referencing the exported code for finding the book data nothing happened.